# how to avoid importing wrong self in eclipse python

Tags: python-3.x, eclipse, pydev, self

I have a python pydev project.
Inside it I have classes.
When trying to use self. eclipse shows me the autocomplete for self and I naturally use it. Then I find that eclipse automatically adds this import line:
"from _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_cython import self"

How can I stop eclipse from importing this wrong 'self' ?

I have eclipse Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0)
Build id: 20190314-1200
and
Brainwy Software Ltda   PyDev - Python Development Environment  7.2.1.201904261721  org.python.pydev.feature

interpreter is set to python 3.5

Thanks

Comment: There is nothing to do with the editor. Particular editor suggests `self.` with defined public methods and public variables of a particular class. I have encountered somewhat similar occurrance in PyCharm editor, later I figured out there is no relationship to editor. Hope this comment would have helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, usually to write `self` in the editor you can type `s` and promptly press enter (if you have the default config PyDev would only show `self` as the single completion at that point... if you already have written `self` then you shouldn't really be asking to complete again -- i.e.: just press `.` or `escape` at that point and don't accept the completion).

Still, I agree that having that completion is a bit strange (it seems to be gotten from the cython analysis from a cython file in the PyDev debugger, which is a bit weird, so, please report this as an issue in: https://www.brainwy.com/tracker/PyDev/).